# How do we keep multiple semantic values during parsing with Happy/Haskell

Tags: haskell, parser-generator, alex, happy

I'm trying to build a simple lexer/parser with Alex/Happy in Haskell, and I would like to
keep some localisation information from the text file into my final AST.

I managed to build a lexer using Alex that build a list of Tokens with localisation:

```
data Token = Token AlexPosn Foo Bar
lexer :: String -> [Token]
```

in my Happy file, when declaring the %token part, I can declare what are the 
semantic part of the token with the $$ symbol

```
%token FOO  { Token _ $$ _ }
```

and in the parsing rule, the $i will refer to this $$.

```
foo_list: FOO  { [$1] }
        | foo_list FOO { $2 : $1 }
```

Is there a way to refer to the AlexPosn part **and** to the Foo part of the FOO token ?
Right now I only know how do refer to only one of them. I can find information on a way to ''add several $$'', and to refer to them afterwards.

Is there a way to do so ?

V.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't seem possible even in the C flex/bison, so it should not be possible directly in haskell or caml.
However, I could use a tuple  
  data Token = Token (AlexPosn,Foo,Bar))
 instead of several arguments.

I'm leaving the question opened for a few days but I think I'll
close it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I did find 2 solutions:

- pack all the meaning data in a tuple, so that $$ point to this tuple, then extract the 
  data by projection:

  ```
  data Token = Token (AlexPosn,Foo) Bar
  %token FOO { Token $$ some_bar }
  rule : FOO  { Ast (fst $1) (snd $1) }
  ```
- do not use $$ at all: if you don't use $$, happy will give you the full token during the parsing, so it is up to you to extract what you really need from this token:

  ```
  data Token = Token AlexPosn Foo Bar
  %token FOO = { Token _ _ some_bar }
  rule : FOO  { Ast (get_pos $1) (get_foo $1) }

  get_pos :: Token -> AlexPosn
  get_foo :: Token -> Foo
  ```

  ...

I think the first one is the most elegant. The second one can be quite heavy in term of lines of code if you are carrying a lot of information: you will have to build "projections" by hand (pattern matching and so on), and doing so in a safe way can be tricky if your token type is quite big.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question - it's saved me a lot of hassle!

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to keep multiple values like this:

```
data Token = Token AlexPosn Foo Bar
%token FOO { Token pos foo some_bar }
rule : FOO { Ast pos foo }
```

Although I'm not sure if Happy actually guarantees that this will always work. The reason for why it (maybe) works is that happy will generate code that pattern matches on `Token pos foo some_bar`, making `pos` and `foo` available in `Ast pos foo`.